# How MDM solutions track android device location?

Tags: android, location, maps, mdm

How mdm solutions like Mass360, airwatch etc find the device location ? What are the possible ways to find android device location from a web console. I expect the result to be accurate.

I am currently using mqtt for communication between web console and android client. whenever the location changes, i send the latitude and longitude using mqtt. based on that the location is updated. But getting the latitude and longitude seems to be inaccurate and changes even if the device remains in the same location.

Help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: GPS isn't that accurate, try to only send it when it changes for XX meter. This will reduce the packets send and will make sure it doesn't change when the device is on the same location. Because technically it isn't, because gps can't measure that precise a telephone not changing its position will have different latitude and longitude each time you measure.

Comment: Thanks Tristan. Which location provider is the best in terms of accuracy?

Comment: GPS is the best way to get the most precise location, more info can be found here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Comment: As per the link , i need to start and stop listening to location listener to find best location. I need to get frequent updates on location. i dont want to stop listening. Any suggestions on how can i implement it??

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be tracked form the agent app you are installing. Simply try to maintain the stale communication between mdm server and the agent app. You may use MQTT or any other push/polling mechanisms here. Always try to reduce the network calls and only update the location if necessary. Otherwise this will drain the battery.